# How to make an object towards the mouse on one Axis - Gamemaker Studio 2

Tags: game-design, movement, game-maker, mouse

I am trying to have my "obj_playership" move towards the Cursor on a single Axis.
Prefer it to be the Vertical Axis.
I tried doing this is an "Execute Code Box" in a step event

"direction = mouse_x"
"speed = 1          "
but the movement looks weird and does not do what I am trying to do.

To better refine my question I'm trying to have my "obj_playership" move just up and down in relation to the mouse, so if I'm moving my mouse up or down the obj_playership" will follow towards the mouse either up or down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check where is the mouse based on the object's position:

```
if (mouse_y - y) > 0 {
    y+=1;
} else if(mouse_y - y) < 0 {
    y-=1;
}
```

This same code could be written in different ways but are a little bit complex to understand XD

```
y += sign(mouse_y - y);
```

The "direction" must be an angle, that's why it looks weird like this.

Comment: The first part is what I Was Trying to do thanks the second part is helpful too if I wanted something more instant.

Comment: If you think it moves slow you can use your own variable for speed.
I've repaired a mistake on the second form